# Applying font color to Excel Row using an XSL variable

Tags: html, css, excel, xml, xslt

I am working on a XSL stylesheet which gives XML output and I am trying to create Excel from it.
I have a reference stylesheet which creates HTML file from it. I have to kind of map this reference stylesheet to give excel file instead of HTML.

I have mapped data correctly but formatting specifically font color and background color I am not able to map correctly.
There is a xsl variable defined (fontBackgroundColor) which defines font color based on action (for example added new action then green font) shown in image 1.

[image: StylesheetForHTML]
[image: SampleHTMLTable]

XSL variable is assigned as class to table row tr  tag (refer image 1).
But in stylesheet for Excel output I am using Row  tag and I am not able to apply XSL variable as a class or style to this row. (Data in excel output prints in default black color).

[image: SnapStylesheetForExcel]
[image: SampleExcelReport]

Is this even possible to retain/apply/map this formatting when creating excel output file?
If yes, any hint is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Note: fontColor and backGroundColor variables used to define fonrBackGroundColor variable are also xsl variables defined according to action taken.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide a [mcve] showing an example of input, your current stylesheet and the expected output (all as code, not pictures) and explain exactly where you're having a problem. Also state which version of XSLT your processor supports.